# how to fix background image and display nav bar horizontally outside of dreamweaver?

Tags: html, css, background-image, dreamweaver, navbar

I want to have the nav bar and logo overlayed on the same banner image.

However, I can't display my banner image. Also, when I preview my page in chrome or explorer rather then the design view of Dreamweaver, my Nav Bar is vertical rather then horizontal.

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7gd5xod6/)

Here's my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
<title>Banner and Navigation menu</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="banner-container">
        <div id="banner">
            <div id="logo-and-nav">
              <a href="#"><img src="../Website pictures/Logo.PNG" width="173" height="87" /></a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="../Website pictures/Nav menu Comic.jpg" alt="Nav menu Comic" width="142" height="108" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="../Website pictures/nav menu mashups.jpg" alt="Nav menu mashups" width="88" height="84" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="../Website pictures/nav menu store.jpg" alt="Nav menu store" style="width:75px;height:75px" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="../Website pictures/search bar.png" alt="search bar" style="width:75px;height:75px" /></a></li>

                <li><a href="#"><img src="../Website pictures/nav menu archive.jpg" alt="nav menu archive" style="width:75px;height:75px" /></a></li>
            </ul>
            </div>
      </div>
        </div>
    </div>
   <div id="new-products-and-sales">
   </div>
   <div id="most-popular-products">
   </div>
   <div id="mugs">
   </div>
   <div id="hats">
   </div>
   <div id="shirts">
   </div>
   <div id="accessories">
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And my css:

```
@charset "utf-8";
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */ 
body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

#banner-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 204px;
    background-color: #0071b2;
}

#banner {
    background-image: url('../css/homepage-banner.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 100% 0;
    width: 1024px;
    height: 204px;
    margin: auto;
}

#logo-and-nav {
    width: 60%;
    height:200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;

}

img {
    border: none;
}

#logo-and-nav ul
{
    text-align: left;
    margin: auto;
    width: 1024px;
}

#logo-and-nav ul li
{
    display: inline;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

#new-products-and-sales
{
width: 500px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: auto;   
}
#most-popular-products
{
    width: 500px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: auto;
}
#mugs
{
    width: 500px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: auto;
}
#hats
{
    width: 500px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: auto;
}
#shirts
{
    width: 500px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: auto;
}
#accessories
{
    width: 500px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: auto;
}
/* CSS Document */
```

Comment: Just a tip, never trust dreamweaver's design window. Always test in a proper browser.

Comment: Cheers. Now how would I do that?

Comment: to handle the display of the image you can use '../' in the image path or remove it. I got the same case as yours.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you want is to set `ul li` in `float`, as follows:

```
ul li{
   float:left;
   padding:10px 0px 10px 0px;
   list-style:none;
}
```

You also can use `display:inline` or `inline-block` for that case, as follows:

```
ul li{
   display:inline;
   padding:10px 0px 10px 0px;
   list-style:none;
}
```

To get logo overlay on the same banner image, you the need place the URL of the image/logo/banner inside `<li></li>`

DEMO in **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alicera/7gd5xod6/1/)**